# "chirp" with arbitrary period

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-chirp

Say you have a linear chirp, which is a bit like a sinusoid with a gradually increasing period, but instead of the linearly increasing period, could you pick an arbitrary value, like the red line in the image below?

[image: a linear chirp, its period, and the period it should have (in red)]

How would you write the definition of this? Say that the period variable is called AP (arbitrary period).

For the linear chirp I refer to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp#Linear_chirp).

Comment: This is frequency modulation, see FM.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create a chirp an arbitrary instantaneous frequency, $f(t)$.
In that case, the phase of the chirp is given by $\varphi(t) = 2 \pi \int f(t)dt$ and your signal in time domain is given by $s(t) = \sin(\varphi(t))$.
For example, in case of a linear chirp  you mentioned, $f(t) = f_0 + \beta t$ (where $\beta$ is the sweep rate) and therefore $s(t) = \sin \left(2 \pi (f_0 t+\frac{1}{2}\beta t^2) \right)$.

Comment: You're missing a factor of $2\pi$ in your relation between frequency and phase.

Comment: so, Jazz, why not edit it?

Comment: Could you maybe give a numerical example please? Using the red line in the image as general idea?